# Norm of operator $T_x(f) = f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vectorspace and $X'$ be the dual space of $X$. For $x \in X$ we can define $T_x: X' \to \mathbb F$ by $T_x(f) := f(x)$. This is indeed an operator in $X''$. I read that $\| T_x \| = \| x \|$ but I could not figure out how to prove this. Can this be done by means of a Hahn-Banach theorem ?

Comment: $\lVert T_x\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$ is elementary. To show equality, you need Hahn-Banach indeed.

Comment: Could you provide some basic steps ?

Comment: Just a small point but an operator in $T''$ would mean a mapping $T'' \mapsto T''$ whereas what we have here is a mapping $T' \mapsto \mathbb{F}$ that is bounded, this means it's in $T''$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for every $f \in X'$,

$$\lvert T_x(f)\rvert = \lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$$

by the definition of the norm on $X'$. That yields $\lVert T_x\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$.

To see the equality, we need, for every $x\neq 0$, to find an $f_x \in X'\setminus\{0\}$ with

$$\lvert f_x(x)\rvert = \lVert f_x\rVert \cdot \lVert x\rVert.$$

The existence of such an $f_x$ follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem, for $x\neq 0$ consider the subspace $M = \mathbb{F}\cdot x$, and the linear functional $\varphi_x \colon M \to \mathbb{F}; \varphi_x(c\cdot x) = c\cdot \lVert x\rVert$. By Hahn-Banach, $\varphi_x$ has an extension $f_x$ of norm $1$.